# When returning Python sets very often, I get a large, unidentified memory usage. With lists the memory stays low

Tags: python, list, memory-management, set

I have a function returning a set and call it very often, leading to large memory usage. Deleting the list with the returned sets does not free the memory. When returning a list instead, much less memory is consumed and it is freed again when deleting the list of returned lists.

```
import sys
large_list = list(range(2_000_000))

def some_function(arg1, arg2=None):
        # return list(range(23)) # --> memory usage: ~650 MB
        return set(list(range(23))) # --> memory usage: ~4 GB

results = []
for x in large_list:
    results.append(some_function(x))
print(f"size results: {sys.getsizeof(results)/1000/1000} MB")
# >>> size results: 17.12828 MB

del results # does not reduce process memory when using sets
```

When calling the for-loop again after deleting `results`, the memory usage does not go up to ~8 GB, so whatever the sets need so much memory for seems to be getting reused.

Can I free the memory if i need to use sets? I have already gotten python to crash when running out of memory.

I'm on linux (Rocky 9.2) and using btop to inspect the memory usage of the process.

Edit:
@Ashwini Chaudhari: When executing the `del`-line by itself, I can immediately see the memory dropping (without explicitly calling the garbage collector). But not the large ~4 GB memory block.

@Klaus D.: This is just an example. The `some_function` would normally make some calculations and return a set, but I ran into memory issues and isolated this problem.

@testfile: But I append the list results from the function to a list, this list does not take up all of the memory when using sets, and with lists the id's are also different:

```
def some_function(arg1, arg2=None):
        return list(range(23)) # --> memory usage: ~650 MB

results = []
for x in range(2):
    results.append(some_function(x))

print(f"id r: {id(results)}")
print(f"id r[0]: {id(results[0])}")
print(f"id r[1]: {id(results[1])}")
```

```
id r: 140151027880896
id r[0]: 140151027733120
id r[1]: 140151027735040
```

Edit 2: See my Answer.
Edit 3: Posted edit 2 as an Answer.

Comment: I hope this is just an example. If you are working with ranges, you can happily drop the `list` and the `set` around it. Most operation on them are very efficient, especially on memory.

Comment: `del` does not always immediately free up memory, as that is something the garbage collector(GC) does. You can explicitly free up the memory using [`gc.collect()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.collect) right after the `del` statement.

CPython also uses "free lists" to cache some types of objects, these are also cleaned up by the GC: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1663f8ba8405fefc82f74f8d1ed86d6f26250658/Modules/gcmodule.c#L968

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some users on the [python forum](https://discuss.python.org/t/when-returning-python-sets-very-often-i-get-a-large-unidentified-memory-usage-with-lists-the-memory-stays-low/29021/2), I found out that the process keeping the memory after `del results` seems to be operating system specific. On windows, the memory is freed after `del results`. Using guppy also revealed the memory usage before `del results`:

```
Partition of a set of 4391442 objects. Total size = 4669488395 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Referrers by Kind (class / dict of class)
     0 4014906  91 4585133761  98 4585133761  98 list
     1   9661   0 35037141   1 4620170902  99 dict of module
     2  96915   2  8329133   0 4628500035  99 types.CodeType
...
```

And after `del results`:

```
Partition of a set of 2391510 objects. Total size = 124367520 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Referrers by Kind (class / dict of class)
     0 2014924  84 57136036  46  57136036  46 list
     1   9659   0 17908691  14  75044727  60 dict of module
     2  96913   4  8328983   7  83373710  67 types.CodeType
...
```

So to guppy / the heap it looks like the memory has been freed, but btop (and htop) still show the memory as belonging to the python process. The memory can then be used to create a new list of sets (as in the original question), but there does not seem to be a way to free the memory if the OS doesn't release it.

Note: `sys.getsizeof` does only return the size of the list, but not the list elements. One set is quite big, compared to a list of the same size:

```py
>>> sys.getsizeof(set(range(23)))
2264
>>> sys.getsizeof(list(range(23)))
240
```

**So it is the sets themselves, that use up a lot of memory.** *Just using lists is the less memory intensive process, although it will make lookups slower.*

Might be interesting if you have to work with lots of small sets: When pickling the list of sets, this results in a small ~100 MB file, (which can also be unpickled which fills up the memory again...).

Answer (score -2):

Touching on the memory usage of `list` vs `set`. Python does some fancy magic when using lists like you are. for example:

```py
def some_function(arg1, arg2=None):
        return list(range(23)) # --> memory usage: ~650 MB

a = some_function(1)
b = some_function(1)
print(f"first address: {id(a)}")
print(f"second address: {id(b)}")

print(f"address of a[0]: {id(a[0])}")
print(f"address of b[0]: {id(b[0])}")
```

prints:

```
first address: 2316573262720
second address: 2316573262784
address of a[0]: 140730959389448
address of b[0]: 140730959389448
```

as we can see both `a` and `b` are separate objects but they both reference the same memory in the first index. So you can make 1000000 lists and it will be a tiny amount of memory since not every list has its own copy of the underlying data. they all just point to the same place.

as for `set` using so much its because it doesnt do the above. when you create a set it allocates a much bigger object into memory 2000000 times. Its that object that takes all the memory up.

as comments have said. `del` doesn't free memory. the Garbage collector does to your del statement doesnt really do much since the ref count will be decremented when the object falls out of scope

Comment: *"as for set using so much its because it doesnt do the above"* - It does.

Comment: please tell me then, when counting the objects with `objgraph` `set` shows up with 2000000 instances in memory when with list its only 1?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `objgraph` and don't know what you did with it.